# search inside dictionary of lists

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm trying to search inside a dictionary of lists 
the list elements are dictionaries

for example, searching for a word inside the articles of NY Times or the post
or if the word is inside both newspapers articles

also, how can I add elements to a specific dictionary (news paper)

```py
news_papers ={
    "NY Times": [
        {"id": 1, "language": "English", "edition": "first", "author": "MR Mike",
         "article": "New york post example"}
    ],

    "the POST": [
        {"id": 1, "language": "English", "edition": "first", "author": "kyle",
         "article": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, ...etc"},

        {"id": 2, "language": "English", "edition": "first", "author": "MR Jake",
         "article": "writing for New york"}
    ]

}
```

Expected results:

if I search the word "New York"

result:

1-Ny times, article id:1

2-the post, article id:2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to iterate over each list and use dictionary keys to get what you want. You also have to be careful about case sensitivity:

```
compamy_article_id = []
for company, paper in news_papers.items():
    for article in paper:
        if search_str.lower() in article['article'].lower():
            compamy_article_id.append((company, article['id']))
```

or one-liner:

```
search_str = 'New York'
compamy_article_id = [(company, article['id']) for company, paper in news_papers.items() for article in paper if search_str.lower() in article['article'].lower()]
```

Then print it:

```
for company, art_id in compamy_article_id:
    print(f"{index + 1}-{company}, artical id: {art_id}")
```

**Output:**

```
1-NY Times, artical id: 1
2-the POST, artical id: 2
```

Answer (score 0):

With a ternary operator:

```
for key, value in news_papers.items():
    print(f'{ (key, value[0].get("id")) if "new york" in value[0].get("article").lower() else "" }')
```

Other answers are more appropriate, this is just a variant sidebar.